# Variables de sesión y URL Amigables

Tags: php, session

Buenas tardes,

Tengo una tienda online funcionando con URL amigables. Todos los productos del carrito se guardan en variables de sesión y tengo acceso a ellas en todo el proyecto excepto en la ficha de producto que curiosamente es la página que más niveles tiene.

forma de guardado de la variable de sesión:

```
$_SESSION["basket"]["items"][$id_item]["quantity"] = $quantity;
```

formas de recoger la variable (en la ficha de producto aparecen vacías, en el resto de pantallas no):

```
var_dump($_SESSION);
echo $_SESSION['basket'];
```

Ejemplo de url donde funciona:

```
http://localhost/es/alimentacion/
```

Ejemplo de url donde no funciona:

```
http://localhost/es/alimentacion/dulces-y-galletas/galletas-saladas/galletas-de-aceite-son-pons-quely#
```

Añado mi htaccess por si puede servir de ayuda:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d  
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/?$ /index.php?idioma=$1  [L]
RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/?$ /hub.php?idioma=$1&group=$2  [L]
RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/?$ /hub.php?idioma=$1&group=$2&family=$3  [L]
RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/?$ /hub.php?idioma=$1&group=$2&family=$3&category=$4  [L]
RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/?$ /hub.php?idioma=$1&group=$2&family=$3&category=$4&product=$5  [L]
```

Answer (score 0):

El .htaccces parece estar bien formado, no obstante observo un par de cosas:

1. Escapa las `/` en la expresión regular.
2. Cuidado con `#` al final de la url

Answer (score 0):

Lo siento pero creo que no va a ser cosa del ***.htaccess*** ni de las ***URLs amigables*** y con la información que has puesto no da para encontrar la solución.

Deberías hacer un seguimiento de por donde va el flujo de tu aplicación y debug de $_SESSION hasta que encuentres el problema.
Empezando por el fichero que carga la ficha de producto donde dices que está vacía ¿Hiciste un **var_dump($_SESSION)**, verdad? Si lo haces al comenzar el fichero y esta vacía, ves hacia atrás, a lo que se ejecuta inmediatamente antes y así hasta que vuelvas a tener datos, en ese tramo intermedio tendrás el problema.